# MySQL can't see database

Tags: mysql, database

```
GRANT SELECT ON source_starcraft.udb_ability TO `wade`@`localhost'
```

When I login with `wade` via PHPMyAdmin I can't see the database `source_starcraft`.  I've only executed this query and created the user prior to this query.

Comment: @Webnet - make sure you had run `flush privileges`

Comment: Good call - though I did that and logging in as wade I still can't see ny other databases than `information_schema`

Comment: alright, where is your database? is it same as phpmyadmin ? the localhost might be the possible cause

Comment: When I'm logged in as myself (global access) I can see all the databases.  So I don't understand your question.... they're all on the same machine and all show up in phpmyadmin

Comment: The 'wade'@'localhost' account can be used only when connecting from the local host. The 'wade'@'%' account uses the '%' wildcard for the host part, so it can be used to connect from any host.

Comment: I'm trying to connect through PHPMyAdmin which is the localhost.  So it should let me in, right?

Comment: depends on phpmyadmin configuration, how about you try to use wildcard to check is that work for wildcard host?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the user you logged into phpMyAdmin with does have the correct permissions to view the database, but you still can't see it, it might mean phpMyAdmin itself has been configured to not show it. This is easiest to verify by issuing a `show databases;` SQL query from within phpMyAdmin. If the database you are looking for shows up, the user is permitted to view it, at the least.

There are several config directives which can controls which databases are visible in phpMyAdmin's lists. If you used an automated installer or script to add phpMyAdmin to a user account, it might also have set one of only_db or hide_db. These are also described in the official phpMyAdmin documentation, which should have been included with your installation, and on the [wiki](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config#only_db).

If your user has access to change the settings, you can do it for the current session from within phpMyAdmin under "Settings" and the "Features" tab. To permanently change these settings you will need to edit [config.inc.php](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/config.inc.php). Its location depends on where phpMyAdmin is installed on your system.

Answer (score 11):

Here something that helped me a lot. Actually I was working with MySQL Workbench.

http://bobfield.blogspot.it/2006/10/i-cant-see-my-databases.html

Briefly, it says that if MySQL has an <anonymous> account, and you fail logging in with your user, you end up logged in as the anonymous user, without notice. To find out this you can do:

```
SELECT user(), current_user();
```

Here's why:

> One important thing to note is that `SELECT USER();` shows you your
>   current username and host. Another command, `SELECT CURRENT_USER();`
>   shows what you're *authenticated* as.

Indeed, in my case, `user()` was `mylogin@localhost`, `current_user()` was `@localhost` (the anon user).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there might me some conflict/confusion with respect to which host the permission was granted to, and which one(s) are being used.

After `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` to remove that possibility, I'd see which user I was being identified as once I was logged in:

```
SELECT user();
```

Note that MySQL always associates a login with the most specific host. See [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connection-access.html). Then compare that to what's in the privileges database.

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE user='wade';

SELECT * FROM mysql.db WHERE user='wade';
```

To resolve the situation, either `REVOKE` or `DELETE`+`FLUSH PRIVILEGES` the trouble-causing conflict (being careful not to paint yourself into a corner), or `GRANT` more privileges to the one your user is identified as.

Comment: `SELECT user()` returns `wade@localhost`

Comment: You got the same SELECT USER() from both command line and phpmyadmin, but can only see the database from the command line?

Comment: Hmmm.... maybe you were/are connecting to a different box with using your non phpmyadmin method?

Comment: It's definitely the same box, it's the only box I have

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue yesterday. I swap my data files HD onto another MySQL server (Same version of everything, replica brand new install same passwords as preventive maintenance). Had both root access, but I guess they are different machines and hashs for the passwords created at MySQL startup. When I listed for files, all are intact in both servers, but phpmyadmin could't see databases (just information_schema), even not available using MySQL thru shell, but files are at the right location.

When check ownership of files they where not owned by root, the owner was **'nobody'**, so I proceded to take ownership of the databases files at MySQL default data location using `chown root:root *`

So if you think that just replacing the data by swapping HDs, and beeing root in both places, with root access on both you will be happy camper. But not so quickly, you may need to check persmission and ownership of those files still to be able to list them in PHPMYADMIN

After that procedure, everything worked OK after reboot.